# react fetch data on button click

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, laravel, axios

I'm trying to fetch data in react. The problem is i have to click on button twice to get that data.
Although i don't get data on first click it somehow renders if I add JSON.stringify to it. If I don't add JSON.stringify it returns undefined. If anyone know what this is please help me

[without clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPUL0.png) 
[on first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/308qE.png) 
[on second click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vzRU.png)

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios'

function Example() {

const [students,setStudents] = useState('')
const [name,setName] = useState('')

const handleClick = async() => {
    const data = await axios.get('api/foo')
    setStudents(data)
    console.log(students)
}

return (
    <div className="container">
        <h2>Example component</h2>
        <button onClick = {handleClick}>Get students</button>
        <div>
            {JSON.stringify(students.data)}
        </div>
    </div>
);
 }

export default Example;

if (document.getElementById('root')) {
     ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that setStudents is an asynchronous function, so I just made student object and added to it loading property

```
const [students,setStudents] = useState({
    data: '',
    loading: true
})
const [name,setName] = useState('')

const handleClick = async() => {
    const data = await axios.get('api/foo')
    setStudents({
        data: data,
        loading: false
    })
}

return (
    <div className="container">
        <h2>Example component</h2>
        <button onClick = {handleClick}>Get students</button>
        <div>
            {students.loading?'':
            students.data.data[0].name}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

}

Comment: I guess the loading should be false then become true , right?

Answer (score 1):

`setStudent` is an asynchronous function. This means the value of `students` won't change immediately after you call `setStudents`.

Try shifting the console.log outside the `handleClick` function. Like this -

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios'

function Example() {

const [students,setStudents] = useState('')
const [name,setName] = useState('')

const handleClick = async() => {
    const data = await axios.get('api/foo')
    setStudents(data)
}

console.log(students)

return (
    <div className="container">
        <h2>Example component</h2>
        <button onClick = {handleClick}>Get students</button>
        <div>
            {JSON.stringify(students.data)}
        </div>
    </div>
);
 }

export default Example;

if (document.getElementById('root')) {
     ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
 }
```

Initially, the value will be an empty string, then it will change to the value from `api/foo`

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is when i try to render `students.data` in jsx without `JSON.stringify` it returns error that `students.data` is undefined. Do I need to use UseEffect hook ?

Answer (score 0):

React hooks are async so when you are running `console.log(students)` right after running `setStudents(data)` it is still not populated, however the 2nd time you click the button it is already populated from the first time you clicked it.

If you want to console the result right after the state setter runs you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61842546/3161811) on another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState } from "react"

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  function fetchHanlde() {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error)
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false))

    return { data, loading, error }
  }

  return <>
    <h1>hook pesonnalisé  </h1>
    <button onClick={fetchHanlde}>get posts</button>

    {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
    {data && <div>
      <ul>
        {data.map(post => (<li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>))}
      </ul>
    </div>}
    {error && <div>error  : {error.message}</div>}
  </>
}


export default App
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).