# SetState with React hooks after axios post

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to figure out how to set my user state with react hooks after an axois post request. Struggling to find a good solution. I've read the react hooks documentation and almost all examples that I find are just when the page loads. I want to setState on form submission as the user logs in.

Login.js

```
   const handleLogin = (evt) => {
    //Prevent default form submission
    evt.preventDefault();

    const loginDetails = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
    }
    //send login request to api
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/login', loginDetails)
    .then((res) => {
      setUser(loginDetails.username);
      history.push('/');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('incorrect password/user');
      history.push('/login');
    })
}
```

Due to the Asynchronous behaviour the state is not being set before the redirect. I have also tried to place the redirect in a useEffect, but it constantly reloads the page, even when I past in a dependency. How to I ensure that my state is being set, passed into my navbar component as a prop before the `history.push('/')` takes effect.

#### Edit

App.js

```
  return (

    <Router history={history} >
      <div className={styles.app}>
          <Navbar user={user}/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route exact path="/blog" component={Blog}/>
            <Route exact path="/blog/create" component={CreateBlog}/>
            <Route exact path="/blog/:id" component={ViewBlog}/>
            <Route path="/demo" component={Demo}/>
            <Route path='/resume' component={Resume}/>
            <Route 
            exact path="/login" 
            render={(props) => (
              <Login loginHandler={handleLogin}
                     usernameHandler={onChangeUsername}
                     passwordHandler={onChangePassword}/>)}
              />
            <Route exact path="/register" render={(props) => (
              <Register usernameHandler={onChangeUsername}
                        passwordHandler={onChangePassword}
                        handleRegister={handleRegister}/>
            )}/>
            
              
          </Switch>
          <Footer/>
      </div>
      
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you post your render method.

Comment: Edit posted with the render/return from App.js

Comment: redux is the answer :)
eg: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/03/02/react-hooks-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example

Comment: You should use setState in useEffect conditionally. If loginDetails.username != null setState(loginDetails.username).Ideally, state management libraries like redux is the better solution.

Comment: `Due to the Asynchronous behaviour the state is not being set before the redirect.` - this usually won't cause too much delays though, it's almost unnoticeable delay. Even if you use redux, it will still take time for state to be updated

Comment: @ Jehad Ahmad Jaghoub I've looked at creating a new simple project to learn redux which I plan on doing. Looking to understand React more before I implement a library. @Arun205 If I useEffect conditionally, where would I implement it. React advises against calling useEffect within a function.

Comment: @rwright94 refer this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954091/how-to-use-callback-with-usestate-hook-in-react

Comment: Using `useEffect` as @Arun205 has suggested is the way to go. However, the condition you check is `loginDetails.username` and if it isn't null, then `history.push('/')`. You'll have to add `loginDetails.username` as a dependency to useEffect. About the other comment about redux being the answer, it is not the answer. It just makes user auth easier because the auth state can be exposed to any component. Lastly, you should have a read on using [private routes](https://dev.to/ibrahimawadhamid/how-to-create-a-private-route-in-react-route-guard-example-for-authenticated-users-only-kin).

Comment: The issue with using the `useEffect` is that `loginDetails` is not a `state variable`, its a const created within the `handleLogin` function to pass with axios. `useEffect` does not know about the `loginDetails`. My problem is getting the information to persist after the push. I already have a `useEffect` dependency attached to the `user` object so that when it changes with setUser it calls `useEffect` to log the data. If I remove the history push it saves that data just fine and logs it to the console. `useEffect` won't work with a if statement as it causes an infinite page reload.

Comment: Would `const history = createBrowserHistory({forceRefresh:true});` cause problems with setting state?

Comment: @rwright94 I'm not sure about the `forceRefresh`, but if `loginDetails` is not a state variable, then use the `user` state variable which you can pass down as a prop to the component. Then in your `useEffect`, you check the truthy value of `user` and `history.push('/')` if it is true. Then add `user` as a dependency. There should not be infinite page reloads if `user` doesn't change (hence the dependency).