# how to get value after updating state in react

Tags: reactjs

I want updated playerNames, so that I can dispatch it,

```
const [playerNames, setPlayersName] = React.useState([])
const onCLick=(event)
{
   setPlayersName(prev=>[...prev,event.target.value])

    dispatch(selectPlayers(playerNames))
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use callback with useState hook in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954091/how-to-use-callback-with-usestate-hook-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `useEffect` hook to get the updated values which works same as `componentDidUpdate`

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(playerNames, 'Updated playerNames value')
}, [playerNames])
```