# How to implement setState callback patten with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, setstate

I have multiple `setState(newState, callback)` statements in my Class component. Now that I'm shifting to using hooks, I am unable to put all of the callbacks in a `useEffect` and call them conditionally.

Some setState calls are not distinguishable with regard to what changes they are making (they may be changing the same array stored in the `useState`) but they all fire very different callbacks. I cannot simply just put different conditions in useState and fire callbacks.

The whole logic is becoming much more complex. How have you handled changing `setState` to `useState` without affecting the callbacks or having to make very complex logic changes inside `useEffect`?

Example code:

```
resetSelections = () => {
    const { filterData, toggleSidebarOnReset, toggleSidebar } = this.props;
    this.setState(
      {
        selections: getSelectionsFromFilterData(filterData),
      },
      () => {
        this.triggerAdvancedFilter();
        if (toggleSidebarOnReset && toggleSidebar) {
          toggleSidebar();
        }
        if (this.props.removeFilterDefaultSelection) {
          this.props.removeFilterDefaultSelection();
        }
      }
    );
  };

addCustomField = filterGroupData => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        customSelectionsMap: {
          ...prevState.customSelectionsMap,
          [filterGroupData.name]: filterGroupData.id,
        },
        selections: {
          ...prevState.selections,
          [filterGroupData.name]: [],
        },
      }),
      () => this.props.addCustomFieldInFilterData(filterGroupData)
    );
  };

removeCustomField = data => {
    const { selections, customSelectionsMap } = this.state;
    const newSelections = { ...selections };
    const newCustomSelectionsMap = { ...customSelectionsMap };
    delete newSelections[data.name];
    delete newCustomSelectionsMap[data.name];

    this.setState(
      {
        selections: newSelections,
        customSelectionsMap: newCustomSelectionsMap,
      },
      () => {
        this.props.removeCustomFieldFromFilterData(data);
        this.triggerAdvancedFilter();
      }
    );
  };

addToSelection = ({ group, name }, isReplace) => {
    const { selections } = this.state;
    if (R.contains(name, selections[group])) return null;
    const pushState = isReplace ? '$set' : '$push';
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        selections: update(prevState.selections, {
          [group]: { [pushState]: [name] },
        }),
      }),
      () => this.triggerAdvancedFilter()
    );
  };
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code or a dummy example? Thanks :)

Comment: @Magofoco Added some examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use callback with useState hook in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954091/how-to-use-callback-with-usestate-hook-in-react)