# How to perform both a spread "operation" AND a callback function with useState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using functional components instead of class-based components.
I have a state of hikes that is an array of objects and whenever I want to add a new hike to that array, I invoke the following line:

```
setCoors((coors=> [...coors, newCoor]))
```

But I also NEED to have the state callback function implemented. This is what Ive tried and it "sort of" works.

```
setCoors({coors:[...coors, newCoor]}, ()=>{console.log(coors)} )
```

But this is what I get back:

```
{
   coors:[
      0: {lat: 37.00, lng: -100.12},
      1: {lat: 88.00, lng: 76.12},
   ]
}
```

But i dont want my coor state to be an object...I need it to be an array like this:

```
{
   [
      0: {lat: 37.00, lng: -100.12},
      1: {lat: 88.00, lng: 76.12},
   ]
}
```

I can probably destructure the object to get what i want but I wanna know if there is an actual solution to this with setState. Does anyone have an idea of achieving this while also implementing a callback function? Thank you in advance

Comment: can u mention Incoming coors value and intialized state type

Comment: Just change `setCoors({ coors: [...coors, newCoor]},...)` to `setCoors([...coors, newCoor],...)` like your did in your first example.

Comment: The [`useState` setter function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) doesn't have a second callback argument, though there are [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54954091/1218980).

Comment: Also note that the syntax of your state examples is invalid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`setState\` callback on react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247433/how-to-use-setstate-callback-on-react-hooks)

Comment: How is the syntax invalid except the extra callback? I mean it accomplishes the wrong thing in the second example but how is the syntax wrong?

Comment: @fast-reflexes I'm talking about the _state_ examples, not the `setCoors` calls.

Comment: Aha, I assume those are just printouts from some console that numbers array entries ... But if not, yes you're right.

Comment: @dineshoz coors is just an object with lat, lng eg 
{ lat: 100, lng: -50}

Comment: @EmileBergeron thank you, but not that answer you are referring to also sets the value to a property of the state.

Comment: @fast-reflexes I tried changing it to `setCoors([...coors, newCoor],...)` like you mentioned but it throws a syntax error

Comment: Set it to exactly `setCoors([...coors, newCoor])`. The trailing `,...)` is meant to reference your added callback at the end and should not be taken literally. But the callback is not officially documented so don't know if that works... But try to add it afterwards...

Comment: @fast-reflexes yea i tried `setCoors([...coors, newCoor], ()=>{console.log(coors)} )` but it doesnt work...im just using useEffect to get by...maybe that is the intended "React way" to achieve what i want? im not too sure.

Comment: Are you saying that `setCoors({coors:[...coors, newCoor]}, ()=>{console.log(coors)} )` works but without the intended outcome but `setCoors([...coors, newCoor], ()=>{console.log(coors)} )` does not? Then it's really odd. But I wouldn't use this two-argument version of `setState` because it's not even documented so even if you say that it works in your first example, it's not bound to stay that way. If you describe your usecase I'm SURE we could come up with something better; there are many ways to do things in React but you gotta do it the React way :)

Comment: You already have the proper way to set the state: `setCoors((coors=> [...coors, newCoor]))` is fine, there's just no callback like in class components. You have to use `useEffect`, just like explained in every answers of the [link I shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56247483/1218980).