# Importing a JS file in TS with Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

In my initial CRA TS app (Webpack, default setup, etc), I have a JS file that I import into a TS file with no problem.

When I switch to Vite, with `vite-plugin-checker`, that same import gives me an error:

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '../../utils/hooks/useStateCallback'. '~/dev/admin_vite_worktree/src/app/utils/hooks/useStateCallback.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

#### `vite.config.ts`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import macrosPlugin from "vite-plugin-babel-macros"
import checker from 'vite-plugin-checker'
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  // This changes the out put dir from dist to build
  // comment this out if that isn't relevant for your project
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
  },
  define: {
    global: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    reactRefresh(),
    svgrPlugin({
      svgrOptions: {
        icon: true,
      },
    }),
    macrosPlugin(),
    checker({
      typescript: true,
      overlay: {
        panelStyle: 'height: 100vh; max-height: unset;'
      }
    })
  ],
});
```

#### `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "types": ["vite/client", "vite-plugin-svgr/client"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "checkJs": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.stories.tsx"
  ]
}
```

How would I fix this? `useStateCallback` is actually copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61842546/6826164, with no typings, and I'd rather not convert it to TS if I can avoid it.

(Probably the best answer is if the same `useStateCallback` functionality is available in a properly typed package somewhere and then I'd just take it out of our codebase haha!)

Comment: Did you solve that somehow? I'm struggling with the same issue:
https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/17s5y4l/imports_without_js_extension_not_working/

Answer (score 0):

**tsconfig.json**

```
"allowJs": false,
```

change it to

```
"allowJs": true,
```