# how to map array result from console.log into table in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios, get

I have an array of results coming from an API that I called using axios. get(). Then the result is in array and I want to map it into table in react js.

Below is the API fetching data

```
const [data, getData] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/authentication/history")
        .then(result =>{
        console.log(result.data.result)
        getData(JSON.stringify(result.data.result))
        console.log(data.length)
        })
    }, [])
```

The line console.log(data.length) returns 0. I dont know why the data is not stored in the data function. That is why when I map {data.map} into  it will return error as data.map is not a function. So, is there a simpler way to display and map this array of result into react js table?

Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEWMC.png) of the array of result (it is not in json type but in array)

Comment: What is `getData`? Is it asynchronous? See also [Is Chrome’s JavaScript console lazy about evaluating objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects).

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to put line which im using useState-> const [data, getData] = useState([])

Comment: @Oyyou apparently intuited your problems. Naming your _setter_ `getData` was your first mistake :) For the reason why you don't immediately see your update, see [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately).

Answer (score 1):

**Update #1**

Since posting this (7 hours ago), I tried to do this myself, and realised I completely invented this feature, and callback isn't actually a function of `useState`

I did some research and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61842546/2156427) very useful function:

```
const useStateCallback = (initialState) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const cbRef = useRef(null); // init mutable ref container for callbacks

  const setStateCallback = useCallback((s, cb) => {
    cbRef.current = cb; // store current, passed callback in ref
    setState(s);
  }, []); // keep object reference stable, exactly like `useState`

  useEffect(() => {
    // cb.current is `null` on initial render,
    // so we only invoke callback on state *updates*
    if (cbRef.current) {
      cbRef.current(state);
      cbRef.current = null; // reset callback after execution
    }
  }, [state]);

  return [state, setStateCallback];
};
```

**Original**

I don't know what `getData` is, but I'll assume it's state, and you have something like this:

```
const [data, getData] = useStateCallback(); // previously useState
```

If that's the case, when you call your `getData`, you can do a callback as the 2nd argument. That callback happens when your state updates successfully:

```
...
getData(JSON.stringify(result.data.result), () => console.log(data.length));
...
```

If that's now how you're doing it, then I'd suggest you change whatever you're doing to be in state, and also rename `getData` to `setData`

**Explanation**

When you're calling your `getData`, you're telling react that you want to update your data? Great! The thing to note is, react doesn't do this update immediately. Instead, it updates it (and other state) in the future, all at the same time.

With that in mind, you pass the callback function as the 2nd argument to tell react what you want to happen once this specific state has been updated

As for `getData` to `setData`? That's because the function doesn't return (`get`) anything, but does `set` something. Makes your code clearer